# iOS Resize TextView To Fit To Screen In Different Size

Tags: ios

I'm using a textview in my ios app but the size isn't fitting in screen. It's being cut in right side. How can I automatically reside to fit screen?

Comment: *Auto layout*. Look it up.

Answer (score 2):

It's better to use AutoSizing. It will be easy to manage it.

**Through Code :**

You can give this property to textfield through code and from storyboard also. 
UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin : It will set textfield from Right Margin;

UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin : It will set textfield from Top Margin

UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth : It will adjust the textfield width as per screen and ratio.

```
 txtField.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin |UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
```

**Through Storyboard :**
It will be easy with storyboard.

I think it will be helpful for you.
[image]

Comment: *Autoresizing* will probably be deprecated in future iOS releases.

Comment: Which one will deprecate first? :)

Comment: I think you need to ask this question to apple.